# How to do calculations based on different text fields?

Tags: google-sheets

I am looking for a more dynamic method to a very manual process I am undertaking in Excel.

I have a pivot table that has multiple values in this format:
[image]

I am calculating the total units sold, avg sales q1, and avg sales q2 for each category for each food group (Candy, Soda). I want my final output to be the the totals of the sales columns for each food group, weighted by the total units. 
[image]

I can calculate that by dividing each category's units by the total units in that food group, and then multiplying the sales values by those weighting factors:
[image]

But I did these calculations manually. **How can I calculate these values in an automated way based off of the food group name and the food group total?** (Candy & Candy Total, e.g.) I have many food groups with different numbers of categories, and they could change based on inputs from a different sheet. So I need a dynamic solution will not break if the food groups or categories are changed, and will do these calculations across many food groups. I am aware of IF statements, but am not sure how I could leverage those to divide and SUM by the correct cells for many food groups.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: I don't see how you are actually coming up with that total in the second picture, could you explain that math? Also as suggested by @player0 please try to provide some data as sample to see how you have  the information in your data to try to help you.